# Android BSD sockets connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm experiencing some issues while trying to connect BSD client socket to the server.
Socket creation and connecting are implemented with JNI. The actual connection is established via java code.

JNI part:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/endian.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_socketclinet_Native_socket
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_socketclinet_Native_connect
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint);

jint JNICALL Java_com_example_socketclinet_Native_socket
(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jint domain, jint type, jint protocol)
{
    return socket(domain, type, protocol);
}

jint JNICALL Java_com_example_socketclinet_Native_connect
(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jint socket, jint address, jint port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(address);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    return connect(socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
}
```

Java native-bridge class:

```
class Native
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("mylib");
    }

    public static final int SOCK_STREAM = 2;
    public static final int AF_INET = 2;

    public static native int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
    public static native int connect(int socket, int address, int port);
}
```

Native class usage:

```
int socket = Native.socket(Native.AF_INET, Native.SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (socket < 0)
{
    System.err.println("Socket error: " + socket);
    return;
}

byte[] address = { .... }; // 192.168.xxx.xxx
int addr = address[0] << 24 | address[1] << 16 | address[2] << 8 | address[3];
int port = ....;

int result = Native.connect(socket, addr, port);
if (result < 0)
{
    System.err.println("Connection failed: " + result);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Connected");
}
```

The "connect" method always returns "0" even if there's no server running (both on device and simulator).

• I have "INTERNET" permission set with the manifest file (without it "socket" function returns -1)
• The same code works perfectly fine on iOS and Mac OS.
• Testing environment: Nexus 5 (4.4.4), android-ndk-r10d

Any help will greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

byte[] is signed in Java, which means your |addr| computation is likely wrong. I suspect you are connecting to a broadcast address, which will always succeed by definition.

Try printing the address from native code through  to verify that, otherwise, try to replace the computation with:

```
int addr = (address[0] & 255) << 24 | 
           (address[1] & 255) << 16 |
           (address[2] & 255) <<  8 |
           (address[3] & 255);
```

To see if that solves the problem.

Comment: You can't connect a TCP socket to a broadcast address.

Comment: @Digit, it didn't work. Also, tried to hardcode the address in the native code - no luck. I ended up writing socket communication code in java and adding a JNI binding (worked like a charm).